# Migrate from t1.micro to t2.micro Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

There is no way to migrate from t1.micro to t2.micro on Amazon directly, I know it.

So, is it gonna be work:

1. Detach EBS volume from current t1
2. Create new t2.micro instance
3. Attach EBS vol to the new t2

Is it safe for a data?

Comment: Can you please describe a little more about your environment and the problem with migrating data you're going to have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This method is actually easier than the one on the amazon forums. It also provides a step by step procedure with images.

http://jsianes.blogspot.jp/2014/07/aws-convert-t1-instances-to-t2.html

The basic idea is to:

1. Shutdown the t1 instance (1) and detach the volume (A)
2. Launch a new t2 instance (2), shut it down and detach the volume (B)
3. Use a temporary t2 instance (3), attach both volumes to it
4. Copy B boot module somewhere and erase all contents of B
5. Copy all the contents from A to B
6. Copy back the boot module to B
7. Terminate 3 and enjoy 2!

Note: If you are rebinding an Elastic IP you will need to replace the ssh keys associated with the previous host

```
ssh-keygen -f "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts" -R <IP>
ssh-keygen -R <IP>
```

Answer (score 0):

Detaching the EBS and attaching it to the new T2 instance, won't work as the EBS volume is still using PV instead of the HVM if this is a root volume. You can follow the steps ChrisC used in the below link which has been verified to work.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=155526